# Python - average all rows and columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get the average for all columns and rows by index for a pandas dataframe?

Here's example data:

```
# dictionary with data
d = {'userid':[100,100,100,101,101],
     'col_a':[1,3,3,np.NaN,4],
    'col_b':[2,5,5,4,4],
    'col_c':[3,4,5,1,np.NaN]}
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# make the userid the index
df = df.set_index('userid')

         col_a  col_b   col_c
userid          
100      1.0    2       3.0
100      3.0    5       4.0
100      3.0    5       5.0
101      NaN    4       1.0
101      4.0    4       NaN
```

Here's my desired result:

```
userid  
100    3.444444444
101    3.25
```

I tried this but I just get an average for each row:

```
df.mean(axis=1)
```

I will be doing this with multiple data frames with different column names and different numbers of columns, so I need a method that works with any number of columns. The dataframes will always have the userid as the index and all columns will be numeric.

Comment: The combination of `groupby` and `mean` is covered in almost any tutorial on PANDAS.  Stack Overflow is not intended to substitute for those resources.

Comment: You can do this just with `df.mean(1,skipna=True).groupby('userid').mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use groupby to make the repeated entries for 100 and 101 aggregate to a new mean.

```
df.mean(axis=1).groupby(by=('userid')).mean()
```

Output:

```
userid
100    3.444444
101    3.250000
dtype: float64
```

Quick edit:

Order of operations matters so make sure you know what you want.

```
df.groupby(by=('userid')).mean().mean(axis=1)
```

Out[4]:

```
userid
100    3.444444
101    3.000000
dtype: float64
```

Lastly, you might want to average them all at the same time (ignoring any kind of order of operations issues), and so you can do this.

```
df.stack()
```

Out[6]:

```
userid       
100     col_a    1.0
        col_b    2.0
        col_c    3.0
        col_a    3.0
        col_b    5.0
        col_c    4.0
        col_a    3.0
        col_b    5.0
        col_c    5.0
101     col_b    4.0
        col_c    1.0
        col_a    4.0
        col_b    4.0
dtype: float64

df.stack().groupby(by=('userid')).mean()
```

Out[9]:

```
userid
100    3.444444
101    3.250000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: np.nanmean(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `mean()` two times. First mean takes individual mean for each column, second mean (over axis 1) takes row means over the grouped `userid`

```
df.mean(1).groupby('userid').mean()
```

```
userid
100    3.444444
101    3.250000
dtype: float64
```